# Why does my action view method work with parentheses and not without it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I created a gem and integrated it in my rails application. When I call my method like this, it works:

```
<div class="container">
    <%= yield %>

    <%= JeuxDuLoto_drawing() %>
</div>
```

but when I call it like, this:

```
<div class="container">
    <%= yield %>

    <%= JeuxDuLoto_drawing %>
</div>
```

I get this error: `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::JeuxDuLoto_drawing`

I used Railties to add this method:

```
module JeuxDuLoto
    class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
        initializer "JeuxDuLoto.action_view" do
            ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
                include JeuxDuLoto::Helper
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The helper module contains my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the parentheses, ruby thinks you are referencing the constant `JeuxDuLoto_drawing` rather than the method of the same name.

Methods usually start with a lower case letter in ruby (and use underscores rather than camel casing) - since constants must start with an uppercase letter this avoids the ambiguity. You can use an initial uppercase letter for methods, but this isn't very common, possibly due to the parentheses limitation you have noticed. One case where I have seen this a few time is for methods that behave a little like constructors (e.g. `Float`,  `CSV`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can inspect it by yourself, what Ruby parser understand when you write `Foo` and when you do `Foo()`.

Define a method as below :

```
def Foo(); 12 ; end
```

Now try to see, how Ruby parser parse it.

```
require 'ripper'
require 'pp'

pp Ripper.sexp("Foo ")
# => [:program, [[:var_ref, [:@const, "Foo", [1, 0]]]]]
```

In the above, the parser thinks `Foo` as a constant. But in the below, it understand `Foo()` as a method.

```
Ripper.sexp("Foo()")
# => [:program, [[:method_add_arg, [:fcall, [:@const, "Foo", [1, 0]]], [:arg_paren, nil]]]]
```

Due to this, when I'll write `Foo`, an definite exception will come `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo`, as I have not defined any constant like `Foo`. But when I'll write `Foo()`, I will get `12`. Use this [Ripper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) lib whenever you want to see, how Ruby parser parse any specific line of Ruby code. Look [`:var_ref`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L4435) and [`:fcall`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L1412).